# Xilinx ISE Design Suite 14.7 not installing

Tags: xilinx-ise

I am trying to install Xilinx Design Suite ISE  14.7 Web pack on my Windows 10, but it stucks at 92%. I tried many times but can't figure out the problem. I even downloaded software again but the problem persists.

All it says is:

> Enable WebTalk to send software, IP, and device usage statics to Xilinx(Always Enabled for WebPack License)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR8th.png)

How should I enable WebTalk? There is no software installed on my computer. On their support website it says it can be enabled from ISE.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Xilinx ISE used to install fine on my Windows 10 machine, but it stopped working for some reason, and now it won't reinstall.

You don't have to enable WebTalk manually. This should be an automatic step in the installation, but for some reason the installation gets stuck.

Note that Windows 8 and above are not officially supported by Xilinx ISE. There is a version for Windows 10 that uses a virtual machine image, did you try to install that? It is not convenient to use, so you might want to try installing older versions or see if you can somehow use the Linux version via Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem; after years of re-installing the non-Win10 version of ISE 14.7 with no issues (and using the libPortability DLL rename fix to get it running), suddenly my install hung on the WebPack step.

Do you have Windows Subsytem for Linux installed? I stumbled across this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xilinx/comments/10ocj7i/ise_147_on_windows_10/), which links this [Exxos post](https://www.exxosforum.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=6052) and this [Github post](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9284), stating that the Xilinx installer tries to enumerate network shares and breaks on the /wsl enumeration.

I disabled WSL, restarted my computer, and was able to complete the ISE installation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while installing **Xilinx ISE Design Suit 14.7 Web pack** on my Windows 10 machine. But I got stuck at **91%**. Later I did some searching of my own and ended up finding that this problem occurred due to having **WSL** installed on my machine.

So what you can do is disable Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL in Windows 10 by following this link [Tenforums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/46769-enable-disable-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl-windows-10-a.html?fbclid=IwAR34bJMtXCIx975dSIKP4Sp8MvUdTAe6UJfFOoytVcm62J-iWjr2FhnnMcA). I hope your problem will be solved by disabling the Windows Subsystem for Linux